# Refresh auth token dynamically when API fails and retry the API call which failed

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-3

I have a token which expires periodically. I am using `AFNetworking 3.0`.

Steps:

1. API is called
2. Token has expired and 401 happens.
3. Need to fetch token
4. Continue the API call with new token

How can I do that, considering that the backend can change the token expiration time?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have a an API Client class that all of your network requests funnel through so that you can catch your 401 failures, parse them for your expired token message in the headers (so you can allow true 401's to pass through) and refresh your tokens before retrying your original request.

You can go a step further by using a session manager to prevent other requests from going out until your token has been completely refreshed, but you basically just need to add refresh logic when your request returns and retry the original request.

Here is a rough idea of how I handle it.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:newRequest completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (response) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            NSString *headerError = [httpResponse.allHeaderFields objectForKey:@"Www-Authenticate"];
            if (headerError) {
                if ([headerError rangeOfString:@"The access token expired"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    //refresh here

                    // exit to avoid calling completion handler
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (httpResponse.statusCode == 401) {
                    // user does not have access
                    NSLog(@"Unauthorized Network Request");
                }
            }
        }

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(response,responseObject,error);
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
```